# Sorting vector of Pointers of Custom Class

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, vector

I have `vector<FPGA*> current_generation_`, which I'd like to sort by `FPGA` member `fitness_` using the `sort_members` function. Applicable code follows:

```
bool sort_members (FPGA* fpga_first, FPGA* fpga_second) {
    return (fpga_first->fitness() < fpga_second->fitness());
};
```

`fpga.hpp`

```
#include <vector>

class FPGA {
    public:
        explicit FPGA(int input_gates, int output_gates, int normal_gates);

        const int fitness();

    protected:
        int fitness_;
};
```

`fpga.cpp`

```
FPGA::FPGA() {
    this->fitness_ = 0;
}

const int FPGA::fitness() {
    return this->fitness_;
}
```

implementation:

```
std::sort(this->current_generation_.begin(), this->current_generation_.end(), sort_members);
```

errors:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_algo.h: In instantiation of ‘void std::__sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = std::__detail::_Node_iterator<std::pair<const int, FPGA*>, false, false>; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<bool (*)(FPGA*, FPGA*)>]’:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_algo.h:4717:78:   required from ‘void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter, _Compare) [with _RAIter = std::__detail::_Node_iterator<std::pair<const int, FPGA*>, false, false>; _Compare = bool (*)(FPGA*, FPGA*)]’

/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_algo.h:1968:22: error: no match for ‘operator-’ (operand types are ‘std::__detail::_Node_iterator<std::pair<const int, FPGA*>, false, false>’ and ‘std::__detail::_Node_iterator<std::pair<const int, FPGA*>, false, false>’)
     std::__lg(__last - __first) * 2,
```

The remainder of the total error string is huge, but I believe is mostly what the compiler believes(falsely) are candidates. I'm not extremely familiar with c++, and a compiler error of this magnitude and complexity is confusing to me.

I can provide more context if needed. Thanks!

EDIT: A dash.

EDIT EDIT: I screwed up, and was trying to sort the wrong member. Hooray.

Comment: `this>current_generation_.end()`

Comment: If this is actually the only problem then this would be a close candidate for *a simple typographical error*

Comment: My bad, issue is in the post, not the source. :/

Comment: Can you copy-paste the definition of `current_generation_`? And are you sure the error is at that particular call to `std::sort`? From the error message `_RandomAccessIterator = std::__detail::_Node_iterator<std::pair<const int, FPGA*>, false, false>` ... that sounds like the iterator for some tree structure, not `std::vector`

Comment: ... I've been at a desk for too long. `vector<FPGA*> current_generation_` is not, in fact, declared as such in `implementation.hpp`. That member happens to be an unordered_map. The member I wanted to sort was `most_fit_members_`. Thank you all for being so willing to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only error that I see is `this>current_generation_.end()` instead that `->`.

In addition you should consider declaring your compare fuction as accepting two `const FPGA*` instead that just `FPGA*`. This will force you to declare `fitness()` as `const int fitness() const` but it makes sense to have it `const`.

Mind that since you are using C++11 you can directly use a lambda:

```
std::sort(data.begin(), data.end(), [](const FPGA* f1, const FPGA* f2) { ... });
```

You also have the choice to overload `operator<` directly:

```
class FPGA {
  ...

  bool operator<(const FPGA* other) const { return fitness_ < other->fitness_; }
}

std::sort(data.begin(), data.end());
```

This could be useful if it doesn't make sense to have other criteria to compare two FPGA instances since you add some semantics to the object itself.

Comment: This answer is great info. Just to add a little more, you usually don't need the `this->member` unless just writing `member` would be ambiguous for the compiler.

Comment: @AnthonyVallée-Dubois: ...or for the programmer.

Comment: Apologies, the typo existed solely in the post, not the source.

Comment: @Bloodyaugust: according to the error I see a `std::__detail::_Node_iterator<std::pair<const int, FPGA*>..` which makes me think you are not using an `std::vector` but something different.

Comment: Thank you much for the extra information, both on lambda usage and proper operator overloading for this particular case!